# How do I Add Values from Worksheet 1 to Another Worksheet in the same Excel File according to an unique ID Nr?

Tags: arrays, excel, vlookup, lookup

I would like to retrieve average daily milk from sheet 1 to sheet 2. Each row has a unique identification number.                                              The average daily milk data exported to sheet 2 is linked to the unique ID Nr. In sheet 1 there are many more unique ID.Nr ( Rows) present than in sheet 2. How do I transfer the data from sheet 1 to sheet 2 in  exact correlation to identification nr, without sorting the rows?

I have tried vlookup function but result is always NA. I belive it should be an array function, as it has too look for ID Nr. and cannot use position of cell.

[image: Raw Data]

Table Sheet1 is on a different Worksheet than Sheet 2 but on same File.

Comment: "I have tried vlookup function..." then please show us what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the index match function. The advantage in comparison to an lookup function is that it handles great amount of data better and also the reference number does not need to be on the far left column.

Answer (score 0):

Vlookup should work just fine. The only thing is that you have to make sure that the Id Nr. in both sheets are the same type (In this case both should be strings since they have "_" in the text). This is how you should use the vlookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

And then copy the formula all the way down in column B of sheet2